# Can I render either rich text or html in a local mode reportviewer?

Tags: reportviewer

I'm using reportviewer 10 mostly, except for one report in 9 (local mode). I'm sending it some strings to display and I want to know if I can use either some kind of html subset or rich text to have the reportviewer nicely format the strings I send.

So, is either of these possible?

Thanks

-Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of hard to find, but yes, you can render at least some html in a textbox in reportviewer 10. I don't think you can in 9 (correct me if I'm wrong).

I don't know yet just how much html is supported.. so far I have only tested the italics tag.

Anyways, to turn it on, you have to click on the "placeholder" in the textbox that is enclosed with square brackets (usually the property name of the object passed) and then right click on the highlighted "placeholder" and go to placeholder properties. In there, you can choose html markup type.

You can also highlight text that is not dynamic in a textbox and right click on it but then the applicable screen will be under "Text Properties". The html markup option is in there, too.